# Core data child tableview not refreshing

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a one (troop) to many (members) relationship using core data. I can successfully add and delete to the troops.

Once troops are created, when I click on a troop from a tableview, it loads a new table of members of that troop. I can successfully add to the members table with correct troop as the parent. Using NSLog, I can see that the member is added. However, the members table does not reload and the new member does not save until I go back and add a new troop. It seems like the only time the context actually saves is when a new troop is added. When a new troop is added, all of the added members will then appear under their correct troops. Completely closing and relaunching the app does not force the member to be saved.

I have tried adding both of these to the insert method:

```
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:newManagedObject mergeChanges:YES];
```

I have added this to the controllerDidChangeContent

```
 [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ContextDidSave" object:self.managedObjectContext];
```

I have added this to the contextDidSave method:

```
[self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

I have added this to the viewWillAppear method:

```
   [self.tableView reloadData];
```

And this to the viewDidLoad method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                             name:@"ContextDidSave" object:nil];
```

I am sure there is something missing or reason why it is not saving. I have also used all of the delegates.

```
<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

I have tried every example or suggestion I can find in stackoverflow. I hope someone has new suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the delegate for you `NSFetchedResultsController`? `fetchedController.delegate = self;`

Comment: Are you using background threads?

Comment: Oh my goodness! That worked. I needed to set the delegate! You are my hero @flexaddicted! Thanks!!

Comment: I replaced my comment with an answer. Mark it as answered if you want. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment

Did you set the delegate for you `NSFetchedResultsController`?

`fetchedController.delegate = self;`